# Git fails to checkout new remote branch

Tags: git, window

I am currently in MASTER branch of my project.

There is another branch named DEV2, When I checkout it, this error message returned:

```
error: invalid path 'src/containers/home/chal/chalDetail /index.js'
```

I saw there was a SPACE character after the word "chalDetail". So I guessed that is the root cause. I have looked up for the solution around but not work yet.

Note: I am working in Windows 10 env. Git version is: " 2.29.2.windows.2"

Comment: Checking out a branch is one thing, but here you're not doing that, you're trying to checkout a *file*. Hum....maybe not, in fact we don't know which command you used. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: "*…there was a SPACE character after the word "chalDetail". So I guessed that is the root cause.*" Yep, exactly. You need to clone to an OS that allows such path names and fix it there.

Comment: @RomainValeri: My command is just "git checkout DEV2" . So sad. Maybe I have to re-install Git and config some thing relate to OS and then go back to this repo.